# What is the correct way to stop a manager thread when managed objects use weak_ptr<>s?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr

A common design pattern is to have a "manager" object that maintains a set of "managed" objects. In C++11 and later, the Manager likely keeps `shared_ptr`s to the Managed objects. If the Managed objects need a reference back to the Manager, they wisely do so by storing a `weak_ptr<Manager>`. The Manager can establish this relationship itself by constructing each Managed object directly (through a factory function, for example), and passing its own `shared_ptr` to the Managed object. The Manager can obtain its own `shared_ptr` by using `shared_from_this()`. None of these choices are required, but they are common and reasonable.

Now consider a Manager that maintains its Managed objects in a separate thread. A user of the Manager-Managed system may ask the Manager to create Managed objects, then `run()` the Manager so that it maintains those objects in the background until `stop()` is called. Still seems perfectly reasonable, right?

But now consider the Manager's destructor. It would be a nasty error to allow its background thread to continue past destruction. So we call `stop()` from the destructor.

Yet this raises a serious issue. Because the Manager is owned by `shared_ptr`s, its destructor will be called precisely when no `shared_ptr` references it. At that point, all `weak_ptr`s to the Manager will be `expired()`. Therefore all of the Managed objects' manager pointers will be invalid. And since the Managed objects are being "worked" (their member functions called) in a separate thread, they may suddenly find themselves with a null manager. If they assume their manager is non-null, the result is an error of one (severe) kind or another.

I see three potential solutions to the problem.

1. **Add explicit checks for non-null manager everywhere it's used in Managed object code.** Yet depending on the complexity of Managed objects, these checks are likely to be fiddly and error-prone.
2. **Ensure that `stop()` is called prior to the manager being destroyed.** Yet this violates the semantics of `shared_ptr`. There is no single owner of Manager: it is shared. So no single object knows when it will die or when it should stop updating. Moreover, it's simply bad form to leave Manager's destructor without a call to stop(): RAII implies that the Manager must deal with its own thread.
3. **Make the Manager detect its own imminent death and *stop calling Managed objects* when it's dying.** This has the benefit of centralizing the burden: the Manager should be able to detect its own death in a few places (for example, loops over all Managed objects) and refuse to deal with Managed objects in those places. Since the Managed objects won't be called, they won't attempt to use their expired `weak_ptr<Manager>`s and therefore won't fail (or need to check them constantly).

Is there a standard, correct way of dealing with this problem? Is the problem as I've framed it in violation of some well-understood principle for design, use of `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`, or use of threads?

The following code illustrates the problem.

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class Manager;
class Managed {
public:

    explicit Managed( shared_ptr< Manager > manager )
    :   m_manager( manager )
    {}

    void doStuff() {
        // Fails because Manager::work() may be continuing to traverse Managed objects in a separate thread
        // while m_manager is in its destructor (and therefore dead).
        assert( m_manager.expired() == false );
        // ...
    }

private:
    weak_ptr< Manager > m_manager;
};

class Manager : public enable_shared_from_this< Manager > {
public:

    ~Manager() {
        stop(); // Problematic: all weak_ptrs to me are now expired(), yet work() continues a moment.
    }

    shared_ptr< Managed > create() {
        assert( !m_thread.joinable() );     // Mustn't be running, to avoid concurrency issues.
        auto managed = make_shared< Managed >( shared_from_this() );
        m_managed.push_back( managed );
        return managed;
    }

    void run() {
        m_continue = true;
        m_thread = thread{ bind( &Manager::work, this ) };
    }

    void stop() {
        m_continue = false;
        if( m_thread.joinable() ) {
            m_thread.join();
        }
    }

private:
    vector< shared_ptr< Managed >> m_managed;
    thread m_thread;
    atomic_bool m_continue{ true };

    void work() {
        while( m_continue ) {
            for( const auto& managed : m_managed ) {
                managed->doStuff();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // Create the manager and a bunch of managed objects.
    auto manager = make_shared< Manager >();
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i ) {
        manager->create();
    }

    // Run for a while.
    manager->run();
    this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::seconds{ 1 } );
    manager.reset();    // Calls manager->stop() indirectly.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get beyond Manager manages managable Managee. Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

Shared pointers do not solve every resource problem.  They solve one particular one that happens to be easy to fix: blindly using shared pointers causes more problems than it fixes in my experience.

Shared pointers are about distributing the right to extend the lifetime of some object to an unbounded set of clients.  Clients who hold weak pointers are people who want to be able to passively know when the object has gone away.  This means they *must* always check, and once it goes away they have no rights to get it back.

If you have singular ownership, then use a unique pointer not a shared pointer.

If you guarantee the workers do not outlive the manager, give them a raw pointer not a weak pointer.

If you want to clean up before you destroy the object, give the unique pointer a custom deleter that does cleanup before delete.

Then, by delete, your workers should all be gone.  Assert, and abort if you fail.

If you want non-unique-pointer semenatics, wrap up your actual manager as a unique pImpl within a wrapper type that offers pseudo-value semantics, and either use a custom deleter or just have the wrapper's destructor call the pre-destruction cleanup code.

`shared_from_this` is no longer involved.